# Invalid Regular Expressions in Express, '/(new)?' - Invalid group

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I have the code

```
app.get('/(new)?', (req, res) => {}
```

Express returns a `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?)))?\/?$/: Invalid group`

I did a little of Troubleshooting and found out that the problem is somehow between the slash and brace. If I do `app.get('/e(new)?', (req, res) => {}` it works just fine...

How can I get around this? Why does this occur?
Please don't hate me for anything stupid I might have done or not finding something on it...

I am using Express 4.17.1.

Comment: If you use a RegExp literal (`app.get(/\/(new)?/, (req, res) => {}`), does that change the outcome?

Comment: Can you also edit your question to include the version of Express you're working with?

Comment: Yes that worked actually. Thank you.

Can you maybe explain why I have to use a literal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RegExp literal instead of encapsulating it in a string:

```
app.get(/\/(new)?/, (req, res) => {}
```

It's tough to say *exactly* why this works over what you had originally, but my best guess is that there you've hit a small edge case in the way that these faux-RegExp patterns are interpreted in Express' route signature parser that is not triggered when expressing the pattern literally this way.

If you're so inclined, you may consider reporting this as an issue in [Express' GitHub repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues) - some of the more involved contributors may be able to pinpoint exactly where in the codebase this pattern causes issues.

Comment: @MySurmise The official guidance on downvotes is to use them when a question "does not show any research effort; [if] it is unclear or not useful". However those with the downvoting privilege are allowed to use them as they see fit. It's much more common to see downvotes on questions, especially when there are deviations in the content that don't adhere fully to the guidance on [ask] (among other Help Center pages). Meta-commentary on how your question is adjudicated by the community (up/downvotes) also invites more downvotes, as it's more respected having a laser-focus on the question itself.

Comment: @MySurmise For more information on voting, I encourage you to visit the [help] as well as [meta].